# What is this method called? (?: PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement, methods

I was given this line of script a few years ago to return a value if set, and I want to add to it, but I'm not actually sure how it works or what the method is called to google it. Could someone point me in the right direction please? :)

```
return constant("SCRIPT_URL") ? "/" . constant("SCRIPT_URL") . "/" : "/";
```

What I don't understand is the question mark and semicolon. I'm assuming it's an if/else situation

Comment: This is called `ternary operator`

Comment: @Marc B Thanks heaps! I've bookmarked that page. Can't believe I've never come across it. :)